# Is it correct to say "What bird's singing brought tears to the king's eyes?"

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say:

> What bird's singing brought tears to the king's eyes?

Comment: What part do you think may not be correct?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Are there any mistakes?")** or **Writing advice (see [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) instead) or critique requests are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: _What_  may be used as an interrogative determiner amongst other things. From [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what): **what** determiner (...) 
A1 used to ​ask for ​information about ​people or things:
What ​time is it?
What ​books did you ​buy? ... >> It is obviously interchangeable with 'which' in some (but not all) sentences. In the example here, it sounds rather dated, and as Ganymede points out, is (unless used to create atmosphere) better replaced by 'which'. In fact, as G. again points out, it is better to reformulate to eliminate the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

It's a correct question formation, but are you asking which bird, or which singing brought the tears?

If asking about the bird, "Which bird's singing..." is clearer.

If asking about the song, "What bird's song brought tears..." is clearer.